# RequireJS + Angular: Undefined app. Callback doesn't shoot

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module, requirejs, amd

I got main.js with this simple code:

```
'use strickt';

require.config({

  paths: {
    'angular'        : 'libs/angular'          ,
    'angular-router' : 'libs/angular-route'    ,
  },
  shim : {
    'angular' : {
      exports : 'angular'
    },
    'angular-router' : {
      deps: ['angular']
    }
  }

});

require(['app'], function (mainApp) {
  console.log(mainApp);
});
```

As you can see, I try to fetch app inside require callback. But all I got its undefined.
Here what I got inside app.js file:

```
define('mainApp', ['angular', 'angular-route'], function (angular) {
  var app = angular.module('mainApp', ['ngRoute']);
  console.log('should be fired from app.js');
  return app;
});
```

So the question:
Function argument 'mainApp' as undefined inside main.js callback seems logical because console.log() inside app.js doesnt shoot. Can somebody tell me what is wrong with it?

Comment: Shouldn't you `require(['angular', 'app'], function(mainApp){...})` in main.js instead?

Comment: why?
Angular included as global throw shim, and passed as argument inside app.js. So it shouldn't be undefined inside require callback.

Maybe I dont realy understand your question. Correct me if it so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove module name in app.js file (or change it to 'app'). You app.js file will look like:

```
define(['angular', 'angular-route'], function (angular) {
  var app = angular.module('mainApp', ['ngRoute']);
  console.log('should be fired from app.js');
  return app;
});
```

> http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#modulename
>
> You can explicitly name modules yourself, but it makes the modules
>   less portable -- if you move the file to another directory you will
>   need to change the name. It is normally best to avoid coding in a name
>   for the module and just let the optimization tool burn in the module
>   names. The optimization tool needs to add the names so that more than
>   one module can be bundled in a file, to allow for faster loading in
>   the browser.